# Any latest experiences from recent daily build of AnkhSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

Does anyone have any experiences from recent daily build of AnkhSVN? Please let me know if it is good to go with?

Secondly does it seamlessly integrate with TortoiseSVN? What I mean here is that if I checkout from within Visual Studio (with AnkhSVN plugin installed), will it be identified by Tortoise SVN that it is a changed file? or the other way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Havent tried that, but have used tortoise for viewing history etc and have both installed without any issue.

For actually committing changes though while using both may work it sounds like a recipe for lots of confusion!
Is there any scenario you are thinking off where you would want to cmimit from explorer via tortoise rather than in vstudio using ankh?

From using ankh (v2.1.744) for a couple of weeks, I'd say there isnt anything you should need to jump out into tortoise for when it comes to commits / merges.  On thing I have found though if you are working as part of a team you need to click update (from pending changes) reguarly to avoid conflicts when commiting.

Comment: Didn't answered the below question
"And does AnkhSVN realise of the action if I have committed any changed(from Visual studio) file using TortoiseSVN? I'm concerned that it should not fail where I use TortoiseSVN simultaneously"
Anyways thanks for the reply and it was good to know you experiences with AnkhSVN

Comment: just tried and when I commited from tortoise ankh did pick that up so the files were removed from my pending changes list (although I did click refresh, so dont know if that is a background process).
Cant think why you'd want to do that, be interested to know what scenarios you were thinking of?  Or was it just a good to know you could work tha way if you wanted to without breaking things

Answer (score 3):

I haven't been using the daily builds, so I can't really help you there. As far as your second question though, yes if you update files in VS tortoise SVN will see that the files have been updated.

Comment: And does AnkhSVN realise of the action if I have committed any changed(from Visual studio) file using TortoiseSVN?
I'm concerned that it should not fail where I use TortoiseSVN simultaneously

Answer (score 3):

AnkhSVN and TortoiseSVN use the same administrative data that is stored in your working copy. This store is used for all management, so they will always see each other administrative changes and the design of the subversion core libraries makes sure they can't break the working copy for each other.

Both products have their own status caches to speed up the showing of the glyphs/icons/overlays. These caches are not essential for the functionality of the products but most users prefer them to be accurate anyway. These glyphs can be out of date in both clients, but refreshing will fix them directly.

The latest stable release of AnkhSVN listens to some of the communication between TortoiseSVN and the Windows explorer to keep the status cache even better up to date than the previos version. (In most cases glyphs will now directly change in AnkhSVN.. just like in the Explorer..)

But even before those changes most AnkhSVN users didn't have any real issues using these  clients side by side (or even with more clients), as ultimately the source code handling only relies on the administrative data.